# Is there a way to make Resque distribute given jobs equally?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, background-process, resque

I have 5 Resque workers setup like this:

```
QUEUE=* rake environment resque:work
QUEUE=* rake environment resque:work
QUEUE=* rake environment resque:work
```

when I run a heavy job like this:

```
100.times do 
Resque.enqueue(DoTheJob)
end
```

First worker gets about 80 of the job and other workers share the rest...

In my case, I may have 40 concurrent and really heavy jobs -video transcoding-. They will be triggered consecutively and I want jobs to be seperated equally or at least fairly to my existing workers (they can be up to 30).

Is there an option or something like that?

How can I achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: if they share the same all 100 jobs belongs to one queue then I guess not

Answer (score 0):

Well, when I try the code above with a simplest Resque worker class structure like this:

```
class MyWorker 
@queue=:test

def self.perform(data)

puts "Testing...."

end

end

100.times do 
Resque.enqueue(MyWorker)
end
```

All the jobs are queued to the same worker.

BUT.

When I put a few seconds `sleep` to the worker, I see that jobs are distrubeted pretty fairly.

```
class MyWorker @queue=:test

def self.perform(data)

puts "Testing...."
sleep 3
end

end
```

I don't know what is Resque's algorythm for this purpose but looks like there's no problem with it.

Comment: I think this relates to the polling interval `INTERVAL` variable.  The default is 5 seconds.  If the worker completes before 5 seconds, presumably it is eligible to pick up a new job.  The 3 second sleep plus (app initialization time) is conceivably enough to make the first worker *ineligible* for a second job at the 5 second mark.  You could probably get this behavior without the `sleep` by specifying `INTERVAL=0.1`.

See: https://github.com/resque/resque#polling-frequency